# Javascript plugin for cross-browser range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, range

Is there cross-browser javascript plugin (jquery/any js library) for handling ranges, especially Firefox's range object(https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range) and Internet Explorer's TextRange (http://www.webreference.com/js/column12/trmethods.html)?

Thanks
Srikanth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATED 15 July 2012**

I''ve written one called Rangy: http://code.google.com/p/rangy. A now-abandoned project with similar goals is [IERange](http://code.google.com/p/ierange), which provides a DOM `Range` wrapper around IE's `TextRange`.

Comment: Thanks. As of now IERange seem to suit my need (especially the method extractContents()). I am eager to see Rangy in action, I will wait for that.